# Integrating Spring with JaxRS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jax-rs

I'm trying integrate Spring with JaxRS:

I'm using this [tutorial.](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/content/en/part1/chapter3/developing_a_jax_rs_restful_service.html)

**Question**: *Page Not Found, when I try to get resource from link: http:// localhost:8080/customers(GET)*

I wrote AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public AppConfig() {
        singletons.add(new CustomerResource());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return empty;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

I've included it in AppInitializer:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {WebConfig.class, AppConfig.class};
    }

    ... some other code ...

}
```

Also I have Customer mode and CustomerResource:

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {

    @GET
    @Path("")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public StreamingOutput getCustomer(){
        ... some code ...
    }

}
```

Comment: What jars/dependencies are you using? And what exactly are you trying to integrate? A spring app and a jax-rs app can coexist without ever having to know anything about each other? Are you trying to add dependency injection into your jax-rs app? Are you able to get the app running with just jax-rs by itself? Please answer all these questions.